# Как в angular-google-maps запретить перетаскивать выше и ниже карты?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api, cordova

В приложение на cordova подключил Angular Google Maps, действовал по примеру https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/quickstart. Проблем с подключением никаких не возникло, все работает. Но если перетаскивать карту к верху или низу, то когда она заканчивается, появляется серый фон. 
Средствами этой библиотеки как-нибудь можно запретить перетаскивание карты за её пределы сверху и снизу, как тут https://www.google.ru/maps/@67.9842268,88.20817,3z? 
В документации по API не нашёл.

Comment: проблема решена здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3